# What is the diferrence between "minute by minute" and "minute after minute"

Tags: differences

I am not a native speaker therefore I would be grateful if someone could explain me what is the diferrence between "minute by minute" and "minute after minute". Thank you.

Comment: “minute ***by*** minute” is used to describe incremental progress.  Minute ***after*** minute is used to describe prolonged waiting

Comment: I'm not sure "minute after minute" is a common English phrase though. A quick Google search came up with a lyric from "Gangsta's Paradise" and this very post. And I rarely ever hear "minute by minute". I probably hear "blow by blow" more often.

Comment: @user124384 I've almost never heard of "blow by blow" before. Do you happen to be British?

Comment: No, but I am from California, so take that for what you will.

Answer (score 1):

Minute by minute is detailed in the sense that not a minute of whatever is being recounted (a business meeting or a sports game, perhaps) is left out. Example:

> From memory, he gave us a minute-my-minute summary of the exciting
>   last game of the World Cup.

Minute after minute means tedium. Example:

> While stuck in the elevator, I endured minute after minute of boredom
>   before the Otis repairman showed up with a smile and a crowbar.

Answer (score 1):

In *X by X* the idea is that someone turns their full attention to each individual X, one by one.

In *X after X* the idea is that there is a long flow of Xs that occur in sequence.

Applying this to minutes, the typical use of *minute by minute* is to describe an exciting event, and the typical use of *minute after minute* is in connection to waiting. Applying the same principle to blows, *blow by blow* is how you describe a battle in full detail, and *blow after blow* is how you experience being beaten up. Similarly, if someone described a child as writing the words *letter by letter*, I would imagine an eager child putting full attention  at the task. But if someone described a child as writing *letter after letter*, I would imagine a child who would rather be outside to play doing their homework very slowly and reluctantly.